# Show middle names in Mail.app

Tags: mail.app

How do I get Mail.app to show a middle name in the "To:" field? Even though I specify a middle name in the address book, it doesn't appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you specify the middle name?

1. Edit contact
2. menubar -> card -> add field -> middle name

[image] add the initial/name to
[image]

It works for me:

[image]

Comment: It works now! I don't know how I added it before... Very odd...